# Get property of dynamic object returned by datacontext.ExecuteQuery

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I'm trying to get data from db.

my controller code:

```
var data = datacontext.executequery<dynamic>("select id, name from sometable");
return View(data);
```

my view code:

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
@item.name
}
```

so when I run it I get error 
'object' does not contain a definition for 'name'

Comment: You get an error on the first line or the item.name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has no business of working because when you are telling LINQ to SQL to do `datacontext.executequery<dynamic>` you are effectively telling it to perform `datacontext.executequery<object>`

Therefore everything your query returns is of, well, `object` type.

The reason for that, is that mapping of the returned types happens by inspecting with reflection the T passed at compile type, and since you passed *dynamic*, at compile time it's equivalent to *object*.

If you really want to do something like that (dynamic API), you may want to look at Dapper - http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/